# build a call graph (json as a output) in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, call-graph, pycallgraph

My problem statement is that i want a call graph of a code in `JSON` format.
i went through  through  different packages of python like `coverage` , `pycallgraph` ,`callgraph` ,`unittest` but none of them were giving output as `JSON`. `pycallgraph` was close to my problem statement but not providing output as `JSON`.

Any good tools to do that (free tools) or any change in above module source to get `JSON` as output?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a statement on pycallgraph docs, it says it can generate json outputs.

please take a look at it [here](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pycallgraph/develop/pycallgraph.pdf).

Comment: Getting below error :-                                                                                                    $ pycallgraph json /homeDesktop/sample.py
usage: pycallgraph [options] OUTPUT_TYPE [output_options] -- SCRIPT.py [ARG ...]
pycallgraph: error: argument output: invalid choice: 'json' (choose from 'graphviz', 'gephi')

Comment: which version of the pycallgraph are you using?

Comment: I am using pycallgraph 1.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of python call graph:

> It  is  able  to  generate  different  types  ofoutputs  and 
>   visualizations.   Initially  Python  Call  Graph  was  only  used 
>   to generate DOT files for GraphViz, and as of version 1.0.0, it can
>   also **generate JSON files**, and GDF files for Gephi. Creating custom
>   outputsis fairly easy by subclassing the Outputclass.

and:

> OUTPUT_MODE can be one of graphviz, gephi and json. python_file.py is a
>   python script that will be traced andafterwards, a call graph
>   visualization will be generated

so either set **OUTPUT-MODE** to **json** or write an own custom subclass